# Status of Tieflings with the worldwound defenders?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, lore, pathfinder-2e, golarion, tiefling

With the worldwound defenders fighting against demons and corrupted members of their own ranks, I'm wondering how tieflings fit in.

The only adventures I got from that area have tieflings as enemies.

I wonder though: Are there any tieflings within the ranks of the defenders (instead of aligned with the demons)? And how are they treated (would guess not so good)?

Is there any info somewhere on that and if so, what does it say in essence?

Comment: I presume since you tagged both editions, you are asking for the lore rather than specifics?

Comment: @JohnP  yepp lore as there is usually no mechanical thing there as far as I'm aware thus also the campaign-settings tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *Blood of Fiends* companion book states (page 10):

> Most tieflings born into the Worldwound proper are enslaved or consumed, and those in surrounding lands are harried from hamlets and towns where they might otherwise live quietly, and generally head a little farther south or west each time to seek a place where they can hide themselves anew.

You can also read on [paizo forums](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2q9cp?Tieflings-and-Kenabres) James Jacobs's opinion on how NPC paladins would treat a tiefling paladin, particularly around the city of Kenabres:

> The way the other paladins are supposed to act toward him depends on the other paladins. Not all paladins are the same. The generalized feel toward tieflings in the Worldwound IS to not trust them, though, so a tiefling paladin will want to be VERY obvious about it and should expect to get the detect evil eye all the time and should work hard at building his reputation.
>
> ... Kenabres's attitude toward tieflings is a city trait, as detailed in GameMastery Guide. ... Basically, in Kenabris, Tieflings pay 150% for anything they buy and face mockery, insult, and perhaps violence.

Comment: So they are mistreated (especially non paladin Tieflings), but are not per se executed or thrown to jail. Only extreme prejudice is used?

Comment: Yes, that is my understanding. Please note that tieflings do not necessarily carry demon blood. Those with a lawful bent could make decent Hellknights, who were amongst the Mendevian Crusaders.

Comment: I know. still though I would dare say that many ppl would just see all tieflings the same in those areas (aka they dont care to differentate).