# Is Kenabres an extreme example for the view on Tieflings and demons at the worldwound?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, lore, pathfinder-2e, golarion

In an answer to my question: [Status of Tieflings with the worldwound defenders?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/163905/status-of-tieflings-with-the-worldwound-defenders) Kenabres was used as an example for how tieflings were viewed.

While creating chars for a worldwound campaign one of my players and I came into a discussion about this. With how much Kenabres itself was mentioned there he thinks that Kenabres is absolutely extreme there while I'm thinking that it is more a typical city there with its views about anything Tiefling and Demonic.

Now my question is:
Is Kenabres an extreme example for the  view on Tieflings and demons at the worldwound?

Comment: I read it too long ago to provide you an answer from it, but you might find Pathfinder Tales: King of Chaos might provide some insight to some of your question. It is a novel, within which a Chellish noble travels the world wound with his Tiefling bodyguard (Radovan). N.b. he is the opposite kind of heritage to the chaotic demons in the worldwound (i.e. devil not demon heritage), which also impacts how the demons present react to him - not just the normal people.

Answer (score 6):

### Kenabres is probably on the extreme side of views

I doubt demons are welcome near any human settlements around the Worldwound, but the Inner Sea World Guide consistently uses words like "zealous", "witch-hunting", and "radical" to describe Kenebres' reaction to demon-kin. It is even cast opposed to other areas of Mendev. I would expect teiflings to be marginally more accepted under other leadership than Kenabres'.

ISWG p119, 121:

> This more subtle campaign produced several crusader defeats, but more importantly it succeeded in inflaming suspicion and paranoia in Mendev. The uneasiness is worst in the border town of Kenabres, where the aging prophet Hulrun leads a zealous pogrom against demon worshipers, and his passion for inquisition remains undimmed by the passing years. In truth, much of the Third Crusade seemed nearly as concerned with purifying the citizenry and the hinterlands of Mendev as with matters on the front lines.

> The small city of Kenabres in the north is the epicenter of the radical zealot and witch-hunting faction under the leadership of the aged prelate Hulrun.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that radical things are, by definition, unusually extreme.